# Disable MS Teams Autostart on Terminalserver

Tags: microsoft-teams, autostart, terminal-server

I need to disable Ms Teams autostart for all users, who sign in on a terminal-server. I dont actually understand how should I do that. Could somebody be so kind and please help me?

Thank you

I tried to create a DWORD File in regedit, but I cannot find Teams application resources in regedit.